# xarray how to respect input dtypes when opening dataset of a nc file

Tags: python, types, type-conversion, python-xarray, dtype

I would like to know how to open a dataset with xarray.open_dataset() and keeping all long the data types of each variables. For example, I have a quality checker variable named POSITION_QC that is "byte" type. When opening it with xarray.open_dataset(), it is now a "float32" type in Python... And when I ask to export to nc file with the to_netcdf(encoding={'POSITION_QC':{'dtype':'byte'}}) command, then I obtain this:

```
TypeError: ufunc 'rint' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

It seems to be a numpy error, but I do not understand since I have used this command before exporting and I still have the above error.

```
xr_dataset['POSITION_QC'] = xr_dataset['POSITION_QC'].astype('byte')
```

It is annoying that xarray always takes liberties whereas I am not asking for this.

Comment: What happens if you don't set the `encoding` field? `xr.open_dataset(...).to_netcdf(...)` should be a perfect round trip. If it isn't, that would be a bug in xarray that would be best reported here: https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues

Comment: If I do not use the encoding field and just run `xr.open_dataset(...).to_netcdf(...)`, I obtain very close file (but not completely identical). The problem is that I have modifications to do on several parameters, and when I do this, their type (int, float, byte etc.) change

Comment: Can you add a sample dataset (or code to produce a small example dataset). A complete and verifiable example will go a long way toward getting this solved.

Answer (score 1):

Using `decode_cf=False` could help but I have a problem with one of my variables which `_FillValue` attribute seems to be wrong for xarray:

```
IN: xr.open_dataset(nc_path, engine='netcdf4', decode_times=False, decode_cf=False).to_netcdf(wd + '\\output_file.nc')
OUT: TypeError: Invalid value for attr '_FillValue': b' '. For serialization to netCDF files, its value must be of one of the following types: str, Number, ndarray, number, list, tuple
```

I tried to change the attribute from `b' '` to `' '` but it created a new dimension for my variable:
`DC_REFERENCE(TIME=280, STRING32=32)` -> `DC_REFERENCE(TIME=280, STRING32=32, string1=1)`